# Set separation between ticks when using log scale on matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

This is the chart I did in 3D using Google Sheets.

[image]

I want to achieve the same scale on matplotlib but using a 3D surface.
The problem is that the ticks on logscale are being placed where they "should be" if it was a normal scale.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(numrec, numtreino)

Z = (numerador/(((rec[0])+(treino[0]*60))/((rec[1])+(treino[1]*60))))*X

# Plot the surface.
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=2, antialiased=True, alpha=0.8)

ax.set_xscale('symlog')
ax.set_yscale('symlog')
ax.invert_xaxis()


# Add a color bar which maps values to colors.
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I think [this issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/209) covers the problem. There are several workarounds mentionned. If you have a problem implementing any of them, please provide a [mcve] of the issue instead of using code with unknown variables as it is now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest), it seems to be a bug in matplotlib.

If you enable a log scale when doing a 3D scatter plot, nothing is created and the program crashes. 
Instead of `ax.set_xscale('log')`, `ax.set_xscale('symlog')` should be used.

To fix the scaling problem I've changed:

```
Z = (numerador/(((rec[0])+(treino[0]*60))/((rec[1])+(treino[1]*60))))*X

# Plot the surface.
```

to:

```
Z = (numerador/(((rec[0])+(treino[0]*60))/((rec[1])+(treino[1]*60))))*X

X = np.log10(X)
Y = np.log10(Y)
# Plot the surface.
```

To set the ticks I've added:

```
zticks = [ 1e3, 1e2, 1e1]
ax.set_xticks(np.log10(zticks))
ax.set_xticklabels(zticks)
```

[image]